# Tmux: Single command to go to a specific pane

Tags: tmux

I have various tooling around tmux and history so I can trace back what happened where (in which pane, in particular).

inside my zsh preexec I am able to log out (for my custom shell command history format) various pieces of information that I associate with the commands I run:

- `$TTY` will show me e.g. `/dev/pts/34`
- `$(tmux display -p "#{window_id} #D")` provides me with e.g. `@4 %28`

Even if I only have the `$TTY`, I can use the output of

`tmux list-panes -a -F '#{pane_tty} #{window_id} #D'`

to map it.

Now I just wanted this workflow: I'm looking at my custom history log and I am able to obtain `@4 %28` but it seems like I have to issue two `tmux` calls to actually focus the pane in question. I have to run

`tmux select-window -t @4 && tmux select-pane -t %28`

Just wondering if theres a more straightforward way. `tmux select-pane -t @4 %28`, or, really, the `select-pane` *probably* should just focus the window for me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm generally satisfied with the simplicity of the `tmux` cli interface... what `select-pane` will do is simply select that pane, and leave the window and session state alone.

In my question I failed to consider the implications of trying to "navigate" to a specific pane if I happen to be attached to a different *session*. The cli will allow me to mutate the current window and current panes of any session at will, as well as switch to any session. We just don't have a friendly interface for doing all of that in a painless way. (an example of how it isnt painless is that session id's look like `$2` so you have to specify these in single-quotes)